# Mostrar mensagem caso registro IN não exista

Tags: sql, firebird

Quero colocar vários números de CPF no `IN` de uma consulta e caso o CPF exista na tabela mostre os dados, mas caso não exista mostre uma coluna indicando que não existe na tabela.

```
Exemplo: 
Select * from trabalhador where cpf in ('11111111111','22222222222','33333333333','44444444444','55555555555')

Na tabela no existe os três primeiros CPF então o resultado seria 

11111111111 Ana 
22222222222 Carla 
33333333333 Maria 
44444444444 CPF NÃO EXISTE 
55555555555 CPF NÃO EXISTE
```

Comment: se houver, tem q retornar `n` colunas da tabela trabalhador, e se não houver, retornar uma só ? onde a query está sendo executada ?

Answer (score 1):

Tenta algo assim:

```
DECLARE @TAB TABLE (
cpf NVARCHAR(255)
)

INSERT INTO @TAB
SELECT '11111111111'
UNION ALL
SELECT '22222222222'
UNION ALL
SELECT '33333333333'
UNION ALL
SELECT '44444444444'
UNION ALL
SELECT '55555555555'

Select T.*, ISNULL(C.cpf, 'NÃO EXISTE') from trabalhador T
RIGHT OUTER JOIN @TAB C
ON T.cpf = C.cpf
```